# Only checkboxes that meets condition should be displayed

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, blazor

I have many checkboxes in my code, but not all are displayed to user.
Only the checkboxes that satisfies condition (`if` condition below) are displayed to user.

Assume NavItem contains "fruits" and "nuts". So 5 checkboxes that met condition are displayed when I use my current code.

My current working code:

```
           <div id="checkboxes">
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                          @if (NavItem.Contains("fruits"))
                                <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" data-id=1 checked="true">
                                    <label>apple</label>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" data-id=2>
                                    <label>banana</label>
                                </li>                                
                                <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" data-id=3>
                                    <label>orange/label>
                                </li>
                            }
                            @if (NavItem.Contains("greens"))
                            {
                                <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" data-id=4>
                                    <label for="checkbox4">spinach</label>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" data-id=5>
                                    <label for="checkbox5">celery</label>
                                </li>
                            }
                            @if (NavItem.Contains("nuts"))
                            {
                                <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox6" data-id=6>
                                    <label for="checkbox6">almond</label>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox7" data-id=7>
                                    <label for="checkbox7">walnut</label>
                                </li>
                            }

                           ................

                  </ul>
            </div>
```

I am rewriting the above code, so that it is easier to read and maintain. Below code works fine, except I have trouble incorporating `if`condition.

```
              @if (NavItem.Contains("fruits") || NavItem.Contains("greens") || NavItem.Contains("nuts")) // `if` does not work as expected
                       @for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++)
                        {
                                   var no = i;
                                   <li class="dropdown-item">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id=@checkboxID[no] data-id=@item>
                                         <label>@ItemName[no]</label>
                                    </li>
                        }

                     @code{
                             List<string> ItemName = new List<string {"dummy", "apple", "banana", "orange", "spinach", "celery", "almond", "walnut"};
                             List<string> checkboxID = new List<string> {"dummy", "checkbox1", "checkbox2", "checkbox3", "checkbox4", "checkbox5", "checkbox6", "checkbox7"};
                          }
```

Same as before, assume NavItem contains "fruits" and "nuts". So, only 5 checkboxes that meets this condition should be displayed. But all 7 are displayed. How do I incorporate `if` in my new code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new version of the code doesn't evaluate each item. If any of the three options are available in `NavItem` than all items are drawn. To replicate the original functionality you'll need to evaluate the range of items to be drawn like you did before.

```
@for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    bool isAvailable = false;
    if (NavItem.Contains("fruits"))
        isAvailable = i >= 1 && i <= 3;

    if (!isAvailable && NavItem.Contains("greens"))
        isAvailable = i >= 4 && i <= 5;

    if (!isAvailable && NavItem.Contains("nuts"))
        isAvailable = i >= 6 && i <= 7;

    if (isAvailable)
    {
        <li class="dropdown-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id=@string.Format("checkbox{0}",i) data-id=@i>
            <label>@ItemName[i]</label>
        </li>
    }
}
```

I personally agree with [Bennyboy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895210/591285) that that your original solution was not quite sustainable. But if you omit the correlation between the `ItemName` and `checkboxID` by removing the `checkboxID` collection like I've shown you than your solution becomes much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the checkboxID suggestion as well!

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your system maintainable, you need to key your information somehow, such that you have an arbitrary collection of categories, and you can easily add new members to whatever category you want.  Normally, the data would come from a database, but here I built some sample data:

```
@page "/"

<h3>My Diet</h3>

@foreach (var category in Categories)
{
    <input style="margin: 3px;" type="checkbox" @bind="Checklist[category]" /> @category.Name
    <br/>
}
<hr />
@foreach (var category in Checklist.Where(c => c.Value == true))
{
    foreach (var item in CheckedFoods.Where(cf => cf.Key.CategoryID == category.Key.ID))
    {
        <input style="margin: 3px;" type="checkbox" @bind="CheckedFoods[item.Key]" /> @item.Key.Name
    }
}
@code {
    record FoodCategory(int ID, string Name);
    record FoodItem(int CategoryID, string Name);
    Dictionary<FoodCategory, bool> Checklist = new();
    Dictionary<FoodItem, bool> CheckedFoods = new();

    List<FoodCategory> Categories = new()
    {
        new (0,"fruits"), new (1,"greens"), new (2, "nuts")
    };

    List<FoodItem> FoodItems = new()
    {
        new (0, "apples"), new (0, "pears"), new (0, "bananas"),
        new (1, "beans"), new (1, "cabbage"), new (1, "boogers"),
        new (2, "almonds"), new (2, "walnuts"), new (2, "pecans"),
    };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Checklist = Categories.ToDictionary(c => c, c => false);
        CheckedFoods = FoodItems.ToDictionary(f => f, f => false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution is great. Thank you for the answer. But I want my data-ids to be same as shown. I use those ids for displaying charts in appropriate containers (based on checkbox selected). For eg: if nuts had been passed, checkbox 6 and 7 are displayed. Data-id for almond and walnut has to be 6 and 7. My code is configured in a way that they will be then displayed in container6 and container7 (when they are checked).

Comment: You're trying to make Blazor not be Blazor, and that will make life harder than it needs to be.  You really have no need for any id at all, or for data-id.  But anyway, good luck, I hope you enjoy Blazor!

Comment: I am still new and trying to learn the blazor way. Thanks again.